# Cassandra 1.1.1 how to insert into DateType Column

Tags: cassandra

I have created a column family having column of type

`{column_name: dob, validation_class: DateType}`

Now I want to insert a date into the column through CLI.

When I try to insert a value it gives the following error:

> "unable to coerce '1988-1-1'T'01:45:12:112' to a  formatted date (long)"

I would be much obliged if anyone could point me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The number of miliseconds since the Unix epoch timestamp for your date (Jan 01 1988 01:45:12.112 GMT+0000 (GMT). I'm assuming GMT here, no timezone was specified) is 567999912112.

Assuming your CF schema definition looks like this:

```
create column family test with column_type='Standard' 
   and key_validation_class = 'UTF8Type' 
   and comparator='UTF8Type'  
   and default_validation_class = 'UTF8Type'
   and column_metadata = [
      {column_name : 'dob', validation_class : DateType}
      ];
```

The following Cassandra CLI command insert your date correctly:

```
set test['userID']['dob']=567999912112;
```

To test it, try:

```
get test['userID'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert you date in an unix epoch timestamp.