# how to insert system date and time through Command Line interface of cassandra in windows

Tags: windows, datetime, cassandra, cassandra-cli

I am new to cassandra.
I want to know how can i insert system date and time through CLI (command line interface) for perticular row.

DateType and TiemUUIDType are just data types for this purpose so how can i use this two data types and insert the date and time for perticular UUID through Internal/ CLI type.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about the current time? If so, take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623432/how-to-get-current-timestamp-with-cql-while-using-command-line/19630738#19630738. (This question relates to CQL.)

Comment: but i want to do the same using CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enter a timeuuid corresponding to now, use the `timeuuid()` function, e.g. ([taken from this example](http://www.datastax.com/docs/0.8/dml/using_cli#inserting-rows-and-columns)):

```
CREATE COLUMN FAMILY blog_entry
  WITH comparator = TimeUUIDType
  AND key_validation_class=UTF8Type
  AND default_validation_class = UTF8Type;

SET blog_entry['yomama'][timeuuid()] = 'I love my new shoes!';
```

To enter a timestamp into a datetime function use the unix timestamp, see the following example ([taken from a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238904/cassandra-1-1-1-how-to-insert-into-datetype-column?rq=1)), where we insert a unix timestamp into a `DateType` column:

```
set test['userID']['dob']=567999912112;
```

Comment: i go through the corresponding question and in that way i executed the steps so at the end when i am fetching data using get test['userID'];

i am getting output something like

(column=dob, value=1988-01-01 07:15:12+0530, timestamp=138305546298400

so here what is 567999912112 and how to decide for entering system datetime?

Comment: 567999912112 is the unix timestamp corresponding to that date ('1988-1-1'T'01:45:12:112' GMT). To insert a date corresponding to current time you need to set the value to be the current [unix timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204669/how-can-i-generate-unix-timestamps).

Comment: ok so dateof(now()) in CQL their is no such thing for CLI right?

Comment: Great, are you happy to mark the answer correct or does it need anything extra?